Filtering specific sequences in R
I am trying to filter a dataset I have obtained after RNASeq Analysis. I have "Sequence Name" assigned to "topological domain" and "transmembrane region". I would like to filter out all those sequences that contain a "topological domain" and "transmembrane region" but keep the ones containing only "topological domain".
I have tried using the filter() function from dplyr but I can only select one or the other. The difficult thing for me is that a sequence can cointain multiple "topological domain" and "transmembrane region".
Here is the code I have used so far:
TMHMM_filter <- filter(TMHMM.df, TMHMM.df$Type  %in%  c("topological domain", "transmembrane domain")) 
head(TMHMM_filter)

The "transmembrane region" is removed but I still have the "Sequence name" with "topological domain".
Here is a part of my data set:
                       Name  Sequence Name                 Type Minimum Maximum Length # Intervals
1   Cytoplasmic (potential) XP_009600001.1   topological domain       1     743    743           1
2   Cytoplasmic (potential) XP_009600003.1   topological domain       1     623    623           1
3   Cytoplasmic (potential) XP_009600004.1   topological domain     360     475    116           1
4 Transmembrane (potential) XP_009600004.1 transmembrane region     339     359     21           1
5 Extracellular (potential) XP_009600004.1   topological domain     155     338    184           1
6 Transmembrane (potential) XP_009600004.1 transmembrane region     134     154     21           1

and what I would like to have is:
                       Name  Sequence Name                 Type Minimum Maximum Length # Intervals
1   Cytoplasmic (potential) XP_009600001.1   topological domain       1     743    743           1
2   Cytoplasmic (potential) XP_009600003.1   topological domain       1     623    623           1


filter(df, !any(Type != 'topological domain'), .by=Sequence.Name)


# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Name                    Sequence.Name  Type               Minimum
  <chr>                   <chr>          <chr>                <dbl>
1 Cytoplasmic (potential) XP_009600001.1 topological domain       1
2 Cytoplasmic (potential) XP_009600003.1 topological domain       1


df <- structure(list(Name = c("Cytoplasmic (potential)", "Cytoplasmic (potential)", 
"Cytoplasmic (potential)", "Transmembrane (potential)", "Extracellular (potential)", 
"Transmembrane (potential)"), Sequence.Name = c("XP_009600001.1", 
"XP_009600003.1", "XP_009600004.1", "XP_009600004.1", "XP_009600004.1", 
"XP_009600004.1"), Type = c("topological domain", "topological domain", 
"topological domain", "transmembrane region", "topological domain", 
"transmembrane region"), Minimum = c(1, 1, 360, 339, 155, 134
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))


Thanks for the code Edward.  I am using an excel file with more than 10 thousands observation and I have tried to run it with your code but when I use  View() I get "No data is available in the table".

I found my mistake, I should have wrote Type and not TMHMM_filter$Type. However, once obtained the csv file, I realized that many sequence with only the topological domain were deleted. Do you know why?

Please edit your post and provide some of the records that were deleted. As you can see, the code works on the data that you provided. Which means you haven't provided enough data. See [MRE].

A simple tidy solution like this does work on your small example.
df %>% 
  group_by(Sequence.Name) %>% 
  filter(n() == 1) %>% 
  ungroup()

It simply groups per sequence name, and then removes every group that has more than one row. Since this does not ungroup automatically, I added the ungroup() bit at the end.
